# Is there a react native package to retrieve nearby Wifi SSIDs for iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

For android I use the package **react-native-android-wifi** to retrieve a list of nearby wifi SSIDs, and I was looking for a similar package in iOS but could not find one.

Is there a package that exists to do this in iOS? If not, can someone please give me an explanation as to why not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. This isn't even possible in a native application; the most you can do is get the SSID of the wireless network the user is currently connected to, using [the CaptiveNetwork API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/systemconfiguration/systemconfiguration_functions).

Comment: I appreciate for your answer. Why would iOS not implement an API for this while Android does? Is there some kind of security concern? Thanks again.

Comment: @NativeCoder Simple: it's not something that apps should need to do. It's also a potential privacy issue, as nearby SSIDs can often be used to estimate a user's location.